# Valgrind Invalid read of size 4 with linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I encountered some problems with my linked list in C.
I'm actually doing a project using sockets connections with a server and clients.
I decided to use a linked list for my clients. This is my structure :

```
typedef struct ClientsList_s {
    int sockfd;
    struct ClientsList_s *next;
} ClientsList_t;
```

So, when I execute my work with valgrind, I got 6 errors from 6 context. Here is an example of one error:

```
Invalid read of size 4
==33211==    at 0x109531: get_max_socket (server.c:26)
==33211==    by 0x1097C2: do_server_loop (server.c:80)
==33211==    by 0x109A40: launch_teams (main.c:53)
==33211==    by 0x109AE6: main (main.c:63)
==33211==  Address 0x4a58040 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 16 free'd
==33211==    at 0x483CA3F: free (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux- 
gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==33211==    by 0x109675: receive_socket_message (server.c:47)
==33211==    by 0x109832: do_server_loop (server.c:86)
==33211==    by 0x109A40: launch_teams (main.c:53)
==33211==    by 0x109AE6: main (main.c:63)
==33211==  Block was alloc'd at
==33211==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux- 
gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==33211==    by 0x10937B: add_client (client.c:18)
==33211==    by 0x109777: check_new_socket (server.c:68)
==33211==    by 0x109816: do_server_loop (server.c:84)
==33211==    by 0x109A40: launch_teams (main.c:53)
==33211==    by 0x109AE6: main (main.c:63)
```

This is the function where the error come from:

```
static int get_max_socket(MasterSocket_t *server, ClientsList_t **clients)
{
    int maxSd = server->sockfd;
    ClientsList_t *temp = *clients;

    FD_ZERO(&server->readfds);
    FD_SET(server->sockfd, &server->readfds);
    while (temp != NULL) {
        if (temp->sockfd > 0)
            FD_SET(temp->sockfd, &server->readfds);
        if (temp->sockfd > maxSd)
            maxSd = temp->sockfd;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return (maxSd);
}
```

So all the errors appear when I close a client and the server is still running. Every line where I use the temp in the while give me an error.
So first I thought it was an initialization problem but it doesn't seem to be that.
Here is my function:

```
void add_client(ClientsList_t **clients, int newSocket, int port)
{
    ClientsList_t *temp = NULL;
    ClientsList_t *last = *clients;

    temp = malloc(sizeof(ClientsList_t));
    temp->sockfd = newSocket;
    temp->next = NULL;
    if (*clients == NULL)
        *clients = temp;
    else {
        while (last->next != NULL)
            last = last->next;
        last->next = temp;
    }
}
```

And there is the function where I destroy an element when i close his client :

```
static void receive_socket_message(ClientsList_t **clients,
                                   MasterSocket_t *server)
{
    ClientsList_t *temp = *clients;
    ClientsList_t *tempDel = NULL;
    int valread = 0;
    int addrlen = 0;
    char buffer[1025];

    while (temp != NULL) {
        if (FD_ISSET(temp->sockfd, &server->readfds)) {
            if ((valread = read(temp->sockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer))) == 0) {
                tempDel = temp;
                temp = temp->next;
                close(tempDel->sockfd);
                free(tempDel);
                continue;
            } else {
                buffer[valread] = '\0';
                printf("%s\n", buffer);
            }
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
```

And in case you wanna test something, there is my loop function :

```
static int check_new_socket(ClientsList_t **clients,
                            MasterSocket_t *server, int port)
{
    int newSocket = 0;

    if (FD_ISSET(server->sockfd, &server->readfds)) {
        if ((newSocket = accept(server->sockfd,
                                (struct sockaddr *)&server->address,
                                (socklen_t *)&server->addrlen)) < 0)
            return (-1);
        add_client(clients, newSocket, port);
    }
    return (0);
}

int do_server_loop(MasterSocket_t server, int port)
{
    int maxSd = 0;
    int activity = 0;
    ClientsList_t *clients = NULL;

    while (true) {
        maxSd = get_max_socket(&server, &clients);
        if ((activity = select(maxSd + 1, &server.readfds,
                               NULL, NULL, NULL)) < 0 
        &&  (errno != EINTR))
            return (-1);
        if (check_new_socket(&clients, &server, port) == -1)
            return (-1);
        receive_socket_message(&clients, &server);
    }
    destroy_clients(clients);
    return (0);
}
```

Thanks for you help.

Comment: When you `receive_socket_message`, you delete the socket node and adjust the list by setting `temp = temp->next`. That's wrong; you've just adjusted a local variable that points to one of the nodes. The list itself, which connects the nodes via the `next` fields, is not aware of that change. You must adjust the link in the list that points to the deleted node, which is either the list's head or the `next` field of the previous node.

Comment: i will also point out that , if this is TCP, your receive logic is incorrect. You do not loop on the recv until you have received the entire message. The code you have will probably work using localhost but not over a real network

Comment: @pm100 Yeah after fixing this i will use a circular buffer so I can receive the entire message and fix this. I was just working in local at the moment.

Comment: @MOehm Okay thank you for your help i didn't notice that point and i'm gonna change this to check if it fix my problem

Comment: @MOehm, do you want to post that as an answer?

Comment: @DanielWalker if I add *clients = NULL; at the end, that destroy the other clients so that's not a good idea

Comment: Ah, my bad.  I misread what that function was doing.

Comment: Posix reserves the names ending in `_t`.  There is much debate to be read, but you really shouldn't use that name.  https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=5081014 https://github.com/WebAssembly/wasm-c-api/issues/55 etc.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Thanks for the tip i'm gonna read that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in `receive_socket_message`: when you free a list element, you do not link the previous node to the next node.

Here is a modified version:

```
static void receive_socket_message(ClientsList_t **clients,
                                   MasterSocket_t *server)
{
    ClientsList_t *temp = *clients;
    ClientsList_t *tempDel = NULL;
    ClientsList_t **link = clients;
    int valread = 0;
    int addrlen = 0;
    char buffer[1025];

    while (temp != NULL) {
        if (FD_ISSET(temp->sockfd, &server->readfds)) {
            if ((valread = read(temp->sockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer))) == 0) {
                tempDel = temp;
                *link = temp = temp->next;
                close(tempDel->sockfd);
                free(tempDel);
                continue;
            } else {
                buffer[valread] = '\0';
                printf("%s\n", buffer);
            }
        }
        link = &temp->next;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it fix only one problem. I don't know why but i was working on that too. When i use only one client at the time and close it it's working well ( so it fixed at least one case ) but when i use multiple clients and i close one client I still got the same errors. I don't really understand why but it seams to be the same problem with a bad link between my linked list